# whats the reason for having time slots in 30 minute intervals?

Tags: time, appointment

What are the usability benefits of having 30-minute intervals for time slots when let's say, booking an appointment?

I can only think that it is because it is easier to remember but what about if a customer wants to book their appointment at 12:10pm because they don't want to have to choose between 1pm and 12pm?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what problem you are specifically trying to solve, and what your efforts are so far?

Comment: Because 1h = 60min, 1/2h = 30 min? Smaller slots might or might not be necessary depending on the context.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are booking appointment with a doctor or say car service maintenance.

**To make most out of specialist time**

Imagine your doctor works from 10:00 to 12:00, strict timing makes it possible to serve 4 patients.
If you allow random time booking there will be gaps and less patinets will be served.

Also most of the time there is no point in appoinments shorter than timeslot, 30min in your particular case.

Same applies to meetings too.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the usability benefits of having 30-minute intervals for time slots when let's say, booking an appointment?

Less options makes it easier to choose one, which make it quicker to fill out a form with less effort. But only if that time option is sufficient for the user and only if it suits whatever it is for, obviously. The question needs far more focus to tell if this is the case. It isn't even clear if we are talking about a form.